# Python SQL loop variables through multiple queries

Tags: python, sql, pandas, for-loop, teradata

I'm having trouble with a Python Teradata (tdodbc) query with looping through the same query with different variables and merging the results. I received good direction in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293006/python-loop-through-same-query-with-different-variables-merge-data-frames/60293504#60293504) and ended up here. My issue now is that the dataframe only ends up with query results of the final variable in the loop, "state5". Unfortunately we have 5 states each in their own databases with the same schema. I can run the same query, but want to loop the variables so I can run for all 5 states and return an appended query. This was easy using SAS Macro variables and mending, but need to bring data to python for EDA and data science.

```
from teradata import tdodbc
udaExec = td.UdaExec(appConfigFile="udaexec.ini")
with udaExec.connect("${dataSourceName}") as session:


    state_dataframes = []
    STATES = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4", "state5"]

    for state in STATES:

    query1 = """database my_db_{};"""

    query2 = """      
        select top 10
        '{}' as state
        ,a.*
        from table_a
        """

    session.execute(query1.format(state))
    session.execute(query2.format(state))

    state_dataframes.append(pd.read_sql(query2, session))
    all_states_df = pd.concat(state_dataframes)
```

Comment: Seems like instead of doing a separate `session.execute(query2.format(state))` you'd want to put the `.format(state)` inside the `read_sql`. Also indent the `for` loop body down to the `append` and leave the `concat` at the same level as `for`. You could also eliminate the list of dataframes and just `append` each `read_sql` to a result dataframe.

Comment: Thank you fred! I'm a beginner in pandas and python. Can you show me the code for the last recommendation on eliminating the data frames.

Comment: I'm also running into an issue if I use volatile tables and loop through where it will say the volatile table is already in use. Would seem like I need to close the connection after each loop?

Comment: You don't have to close the connection; you can explicitly DROP a volatile table or just  DELETE the contents for each iteration. Or perhaps better, you could also accumulate data in a volatile table and then do one read_sql to get it into a dataframe; that would probably be fastest overall. It occurs to me now that DataFrame.append does not happen in-place, so the state_dataframes list with one append at the end is probably better. But for completeness: the idea was to start with an empty dataframe and have each iteration do `df = df.append(pd.read_sql(query2.format(state), session))`.

Comment: Thanks @Fred. I was having issues with dropping the tables and receiving an ET or Null after DDL error. I was able to get it fixed and will post the answer.

Comment: @Fred, you *do* want to use list of dataframes. What you recommend is the ill-advised [quadratic copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451) running `DataFrame.append` in a `for` loop. Or better is to use one `read_sql` call.

Comment: @Parfait - agreed. The list is much better than having DataFrame.append inside the loop. And creating the full result set in the database and using one `read_sql` would be better still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get this to work although it may not be the most eloquent way to do it. I did try to do the drop tables as a single variable "query5" but was receiving a DDL error. Once I separated each drop table into it's own session.execute, it worked.

```
udaExec = td.UdaExec(appConfigFile="udaexec.ini")

with udaExec.connect("${dataSourceName}") as session:

    state_dataframes = []
    STATES = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4", "state5"]

    for state in STATES:

            query1 = """database my_db_{};"""

            query2 = """   
            create set volatile table v_table
            ,no fallback, no before journal, no after journal as
            (  
            select top 10
            '{}' as state
            ,t.*
            from table t
            )   
            with data
            primary index (dw_key)  
            on commit preserve rows;
            """

            query3 = """
            create set volatile table v_table_2
            ,no fallback, no before journal, no after journal as
            (  
            select t.*
            from v_table t
            )   
            with data
            primary index (dw_key)  
            on commit preserve rows;

            """

            query4 = """

            select t.* 
            from v_table_2 t

            """

            session.execute(query1.format(state))
            session.execute(query2.format(state))
            session.execute(query3)
            state_dataframes.append(pd.read_sql(query4, session))
            session.execute("DROP TABLE v_table")
            session.execute("DROP TABLE v_table_2")

    all_states_df = pd.concat(state_dataframes)
```

Edit for clarity: correcting the query in the question only required proper indentation. In my Teradata environment I have limited spool space which requires building many vol tables to break apart queries. Since I spent a good amount of time trying to solve this, I added to the answer to help others who may run into this scenario.

Comment: OK. Yes, DROP has to be executed on its own. You don't need to `session.execute(query4)` since it is being run as part of the `read_sql` anyway. And in this (possibly "sanitized") example there's no need to copy one Volatile table to another with a different Primary index.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Teradata but please explain to current and future readers the need to use volatile tables. Wouldn't proper indentation of `for` loop resolve your original question above?

Comment: You're correct. I added vol tables as some users may have spool space limitations and need to break up queries in teradata. I spent a good amount of time solving for this so thought it would be helpful to others. The first query will work with proper indentation. I will edit the answer for that clarity.